# Find device type on airplay

Tags: ios, objective-c, airplay

When I press the airplay button the list of the devices that are available are shown. How do i get the device type (Apple TV , Bluetooth speaker, etc) when connecting using airplay.

Comment: Have you got any updates on this? am also searching for this

Comment: No comments so far